# How to send a signed DocuSign Document back to Salesforce Record?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

After the recipient signs the document, I would like the newly signed document to be sent to the associated salesforce record. I am struggling to write data from docusign back to salesforce after the docusign document signing is complete. I have attached the permission set used by my connect user as well as the connect setting integrations between docusign and salesforce. I have also ensured that the 'Use content files' is enabled under content settings.Is there anything else I am missing here?

[Connect integration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMxWR.png)

[permission settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCMCm.png)

Answer (score 0):

### If you're using one of DocuSign's Salesforce integration products

Writeback of data and the signed documents are handled automatically as a part of the product. If you're having a problem, contact DocuSign Customer Support.

### If you don't have a DocuSign Salesforce integration product

In this case, you'll need to implement everything manually. The DocuSign Connect Salesforce options only apply if you have a DocuSign for Salesforce package installed.

Comment: I am doing everything manually. After looking at the logs in docusign I noticed I was missing required fields necessary for the SF Object. I made custom envelop fields to map to the required salesforce fields. The logs say that everything was sent back to SF successfully, but I still don't see the document attached to the record